# How to increase performance on Azure inbuilt SQL Serverless Pool in Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

We are currently extracting multiple tables from Azure SQL Servereless pool in Synapse. Unlike a regular Azure SQL Database it is very easy to increase the performance from Basic all the way through to Premium or Business continuity.

Can someone let me know how to go about increasing the performance of Azure SQL Serverles Pool in synapse?

Comment: The Serverless SQL pool ("built-in") does not offer any configuration options. Its size is preset to "Auto" and cannot be changed. Are you seeing a specific performance problem?

Comment: Hi @JoelCochran, thanks for reaching. Sorry for the delayed response. Basically, I'm seeing poor performance when ingesting tables from Serverless SQL Pool.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Ingesting how?

Comment: Serverless SQL Pool doesn't have any local storage in it. It queries data stored in ADLS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serverless SQL pool is a distributed data processing system and it doesn't have any inbuilt storage to store data. It uses external table to query the data from Azure data lake storage. Therefore, data cannot be copied to the serverless SQL pool. If data needs to be extracted from serverless SQL pool, you can extract data directly from the underlying external storage. If the target datastore supports polybase data loading, use that to load to the target table from ADLS.